# while doesn't wait for first gets()

Tags: c

```
printf("How many words to play with:");
scanf("%d",&end);
printf("How many letters to play with:");
scanf("%d",&let);
char a[let];
char b[let];
        while(i<end){
        ranW(let);
        printf("Word: %s\n:",a);
        gets(b);

        if (strcmp(a,b) == 0) {
            printf("Match\n");
            ++i;
        } else {
            printf("Do not match\n");
        }
    }
```

in part

```
    printf("Word: %s\n:",a);
    gets(b);
```

it just jumps to the next argument in the first loop and does not wait for input. But continues just fine in the other loops. I'm new on the site soo i coulnt post all my code if you need the rest i can provide it.

Comment: Maybe you've reached the `EOF`?

Comment: Or maybe input got piped into the process?

Comment: [Never, ever use `gets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/1679849)

Comment: Don't post all your code if it is long. Instead, do post a [mcve]. Also include exactly what input you provided.

Comment: Solved it by using scanf to get the char whank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i used this code to solve the problems.

```
ranW(let, a);
printf("Word: %s\n",a);
fflush(stdin);
fgets(b,(sizeof b)+1 ,stdin);
```

I can still use advice if this is not right to use.